# Windows 8.1 everything requires admin

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, permissions

Randomly everything on my Windows 8.1 machine requires admin permission. I believe it has something to do with the most recent release on 1/13, because as early as last weekend everything was working fine.

Now I can't even download a picture to my desktop; it says I don't have permission. I've checked my user account and I am an 'administrator'. Anyone know anything about this? My user is a 'Local Account'.

Everytime I tried to move a file between drives I had to give admin permission. Saving a file to the desktop prompts me for admin permissions, deleting from the desktop prompts me for admin permissions

**EDIT**
Starting the computer in safe mode, it doesnt prompt me for admin permissions anymore

**EDIT**
If I create a new admin account on the system, this account does not have the same problems as my account. The test admin account is able to put things on it's Desktop without getting prompted for admin permissions. I've also installed any and all updates I could find.

Comment: I believe this might have to do folder ownership changes. What do you see when you run this command: `dir /A:D /Q %USERPROFILE%`?

Comment: By "Everything" does that also include any actions aside from saving/copying file?  Have you ensured your account has proper permissions to the folders the drive you are copying to?  Does it work as expected in Safe Mode? How about while logged in as a new Administrator user account?

Comment: @Vinayak I see a bunch of different directories, it looks like everything under my home folder. Something specific I should look for?

Comment: @Josh What do you see after `<DIR>`? Do you see your username? (e.g. `COMPUTER-NAME\YourUserName`)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 creating a new folder on my desktop has the admin badge next to it (like it will require admin perms). my account should have proper permissions; im the only account, and i havent changed anything! it worked fine before the update. i could make a new adminstrator account, but id rather not... i can try safe mode

Comment: @Vinayak yep, after `Dir` I see `COMPUTER-NAME\Josh` in the next column

Comment: "i havent changed anything" well then it must not be broken then, right?  "i could make a new adminstrator account, but id rather not" I'd rather not go to work everyday, but..... Anyhow, you seem to be a little allergic to actually troubleshooting this problem with us so I'll bow out. Good luck!

Comment: Well, I found out about this: [Reset security settings](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-reset-windows-security-settings-to-its-defaults). I've never tried it so I can't vouch for it, but it does look promising. You can read more about it [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313222)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup all of your files to a drive. Reinstall Windows. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-8/clean-install

Comment: yep. that's what ive started doing.